# OWASP metadata/error leakages -Cannot fire any of the rules

Tags: curl, owasp, mod-security

Cannot fire any of OWASP Metadata/Error Leakages
rules:

- The Application Returned a 500-Level Status Code, 950100
- Directory Listing. 950130
- Java Errors, 952110
- PHP Information Leakage, 953100
- PHP source code leakage, 953110
  ect

All other rules and categories off MODSECURITY OWASP was able to fire successfully using curl